# Linear mixed model / cross-lagged panel model for longitudinal relationship between imaging metric and symptoms on continuous scale?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, neuroimaging

**Background**
I'm working with longitudinal volumetric brain data and psychiatric symptoms, measured simultaneously at two time points during childhood (let's call them brain1, brain2, symptom1, symptom2). I'm trying to come up with a model to best analyze the data. I'm new to longitudinal data analysis, still struggling a bit with designing the right approach.

Both are continuous variables. Brain is normally distributed, symptoms with slight positive skew. I've already found a cross-sectional association between brain and symptoms at t1. I have no a priori hypothesis about directionality (i.e. brain predicts symptoms or vice versa) for the longitudinal model.

**Question**
What model to use for studying the longitudinal relationship between brain metric and symptoms?

**Considerations**

- Cross-lagged panel models. Since I have no hypothesis on directionality, I considered using CLPM - so predicting symptom2 from brain1 and vice versa). But, as I understand correctly does not allow you to account for random effects of subject. Also, there seems to be some controversy about the utility of CLPM.
- Linear mixed-effects models. Choosing one variable as the independent and applying LME. symptom1 predicting brain over time, accounting for random effects of subject.
- How to account for age? There is some spread between children on the age of measurement, as well as the time between measurements. Since these are developing children, I believe both could have a strong influence on symptom scores and brain metrics. Some ideas, include age1 and delta-age as separate terms as a covariate, or model symptom*age interaction term?
- Would it be possible to include change in both variables in one model? For instance, delta-symptoms predicting change in brain, accounting for random effects of subject. It could be that a steep increase in symptoms is more strongly related to brain changes. Or extracting latent profiles of symptom changes and use profile as a predictor to model brain change (maybe a bit far-fetched with only two time points).

Thanks!